# Some properties of conjugate

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $S$ be a subset of $G$, define $S^x = x^{-1}Sx$ where $x \in G$. How can I prove that

(a) If $H, K$ are subgroups of $G$ such that $HK=G$, then $H^xK^y=G$ for all $x, y \in G$.

(b) If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $H^xH=G$ for some $x \in G$, then $H=G$.

I tried to move $x$'s and $y$'s around but without commutativity I could make no progress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first part we are going to make use of the fact that if $HK$ is a subgroup then we have that $HK = KH$. Now as $x,y \in HK$ we have that $x=h_1k_1$ and $y=k_2h_2$. Then we have that:

$$H^xK^y = H^{k_1}K^{h_2}= k_1^{-1}Hk_1h_2^{-1}Kh_2 = HK = G$$

The last part follows as $HK = KH$. This means that $k_1^{-1}H = Hk_3$, for example and then you can make such switches to get rid of the elements.

For the second part we let $x=uv$ where $u \in H, v \in H^x$ by the condition. Then we have:

$$H^x = \left(H^x\right)^{v^{-1}} = H^u = H$$

This follows as $u \in H$ and $v^{-1} \in H^x$. Thus we have:

$$H^xH = HH = G$$

Hence the proof.